# How do I make a C++ template class that changes its members and accessors depending on the class of the template value?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that will be instantiated millions of times. It's a C++ template. The class keeps track of a count for every value, and the values are of type `T` (where `T` is the template parameter).

I have a special case in which the count *is* the value being tracked. In this case I would like to dispense with the templated instance variable and instead just have the count.

For example, here is a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template <typename T>
class A {
private:
    T var_;
    uint64_t count_;
public:
    A(T v):var_(v),count(0){ }
    uint64_t count() const { return count_;}
    T var() const { return var_;}
    void inc_count();
};

template <typename T> void A<T>::inc_count() {
    count_++;
};

template <typename T> std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const A<T> &e) {
    os << e.count() << "=" << e.var();
    return os;
};


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    A<int> a(3);

    a.inc_count();
    std::cout << a << "\n";

    a.inc_count();
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

I would like to be able to instantiate as:

```
A<uint64_t> deg(1);
```

In this case, I'd like to have the `count_` variable set to `1` and have the method `var()` return `count()`.

Is there any way to do this?

(This is a contrived example, but it is the essence of the problem that I am having.)

Comment: Which C++ book are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use explicit specialization:

```
template<> class A<uint64_t> { /* whatever you like goes here */ };
```

Comment: So you are saying to create two separate versions of the class, one that is explicit, one that isn't, but have all of the same code otherwise? That seems really wasteful. I want to only have one copy of all of the definitions. Can I have a base-class that uses explicit specialization and then have a templates subclass that grabs the appropriate base-class?

Comment: Absolutely.  You can split out the parts that need specializing in any number of ways.  I realize it's a contrived example, but in this case I would probably define a base class that contains the count_ and then a parameterized subclass (with an explicit specialization for uint64_t).